# VirtualBox: Start tag expected, '<' not found

Tags: virtualbox

After restarting VirtualBox on a hard drive almost full, the VM I was using in "unaccessible", with this error message:

```
Start tag expected, '<' not found
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Check the files of the VM in the VirtualBox VMs folder.

If the `.vbox` file has size zero, then copy the `.vbox-prev` file on it.

Restart VirtualBox, it should be repaired.

Comment: On Windows XP, I found the file in 
"C:\Documents and Settings\username\.VirtualBox\Copy of VirtualBox.xml-prev" and copied it to 
"C:\Documents and Settings\username\.VirtualBox\VirtualBox.xml" .

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the configuration file where the machine settings are stored is screwd up..
The easiest thing to try is to create a new machine whith the same settings as the one not working; but when it asks for creating a new harddrive, select use an existing image and select the image for your virtual machine's harddisk (probably work.vdi)..

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, but I found that starting the VirtualBox from the terminal as root just worked.

`sudo virtualbox`

(For those who don't want to take the risk losing their VMs)

Answer (score 0):

The answer that I found to fix it was:

1.- Open the `.vbox` file with Editor, you could see if your file is empty, contains logs or is not complete. (In my case the file contains logs)

2.- Create a new vm with the same specs that your previous vm.

3.- Copy the new `.vbox`, and paste in your vm that contains the error.

4.- Edit the `.vbox` in the vm with errors.

Update the value `<Machine uuid=` with a new value, in this case could add 1.

Example: `New.vbox e64e0000-b000-00e0-bc4a-9f0aaa97d680` then you can update in the following way `e64e0000-b000-00e0-bc4a-9f0aaa97d681`.

In the field `<Image uuid="` you need to write the id of your last snapshots.
Start the vm with the new .vbox